# .htaccess spits our full URL rewritten URL on folder name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sandbox/

RewriteRule ^(assets)($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ lib/script/bootstrap.php?route=$1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

What I am doing is redirecting all requests (except for my assets - img, css, js) to my bootstrap script, which will handle the request via the **route** parameter, which includes the URL request.

This works fine in most cases, except for when I have a call such as:

*http://www.example.com/sandbox/admin*, where admin is a folder that exists in my directory, amongst other folders. This folder contains various pages that are accessible, aswell as an **index.php** file that my bootstrap.php routing will redirect requests from the above URL to it, by default.

My problem is that when I attempt to hit the page: *http://www.example.com/sandbox/admin*, my htaccess (as far as I know) is rewriting the visible URL to *http://www.example.com/sandbox/admin/?route=admin.php*, which is not as pretty. I believe it's because there's some conflict going on with the fact that the above URL is a valid URL pointing to my /admin/ folder, but I would like my .htaccess to ignore this and send this aswell to my bootstrap.php (line 4 of my .htaccess). What am I doing wrong?

Here is the requests coming in my browser:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Strangely, *http://www.example.com/sandbox/admin/* works fine, but not *http://www.example.com/sandbox/admin* (notice the trailing slash).

Comment: It doesn't look like your rule should cause that, but it is possible that your browser is caching an earlier attempt. Try it out in a private/incognito window or other browser. Do you get the same behavior?  Without a `[R]` or different domain, I can't see how your rule would cause a full browser redirection.

Comment: Yes, still seems to do it in icognito; also tried restarting my server. So the URL being rewritten in my browser can only be caused by a redirection?

Comment: Yes - if you watch the browser's network console, you should see it first request `/sandbox/admin` then get redirected with a 301 or 302 to `/sandbox/admin/route=admin.php`. Do you have anything else in .htaccess or is what you posted all of it?

Comment: That's all of my .htaccess. I'll add what I see in my console, I believe I'm seeing exactly what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have real folders you need to use a condition to ignore `real` files and folders. All other requests will get routed to your bootstrap file. (If I understand your issue correctly.)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sandbox/

RewriteRule ^(assets)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ lib/script/bootstrap.php?route=$1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: The `RewriteCond` is definitely needed but that still doesn't explain why it's being redirected instead of mistakenly sent into a rewrite loop.

Comment: I can see how this would normally work, but I have the following file: /admin/index.php, which seems to be picked up by your .htaccess code without jumping into my bootstrap.php (I've got a kill in my bootstrap to see if it's going through there, but it's throwing a ton of unloaded .php function from the index.php file, which means that my bootstrap hasn't loaded.

Comment: @Prusprus so you need `admin/index.php` to be routed through the bootstrap file?

Comment: so I would need /admin and /admin/index to be routed - /admin would be handled by my bootstrap to point to /admin/index.php by default.

Comment: However, /admin/ does work 100% fine - it's just /admin (see update to question for full URLs example)

Comment: @Prusprus Did you try adding an optional slash to your rule so it should should work with or without the `/`? Like this `^(.*)/?$` See my update.

Comment: Still no luck; I still get a 301 redirect.